# Is there a name for the category containing the words trans and cis?

Tags: single-word-requests, sexual-minorities

*Gender* is the name of the category that contains the words *male*, *female*, and others. The words *trans* and *cis* are not genders, rather they describe the state of one's gender: i.e. *trans* refers to one whose gender has changed from that which they were assigned at birth, while *cis* refers to one whose gender has not changed.

Is there a word that describes the category of words that includes *trans* and *cis*? In other words, similarly to how one could say "My gender is female", is there a word that fills the blank in "My ____ is cis?"

Comment: It's some sort of chemical, but that class was 50 years ago, so I don't remember which category.

Comment: *Cis* means [on or to this or the near side of; short of](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/cis#Latin). *Trans* is not in general the antonym but just the Latin for "across". It is used where an antonym is required. Not only is it used in gender identity but we are all familiar with *cis-fats* and *trans-fats* which take their names from the chemical use that @hotlicks remembers: [molecule with bits on the same side/different sides](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cis–trans_isomerism). But the contrast goes back to Roman geography [Cisalpine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisalpine_Gaul)

Comment: @HotLicks I believe you're looking for "Cis–trans isomerism, also known as geometric isomerism or configurational isomerism" From good old organic chemistry

Answer (score 3):

Cis and trans, standing alone, used as adjectives, in relation to gender, are *gender identity* terms. They are shortenings of 'cisgender' and 'transgender'. Cis and trans are used as prefixes in academic writing (mainly chemistry) to mean "on the same side" and "on the opposite side" respectively.

[Cis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cis)
[Trans](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trans)

Comment: Cis and trans don't just mean "same" and "opposite". If they did they might mean "gay" and "straight". They mean "on the same side" and "on the opposite side". It says if your gender identity matches the sex assigned at birth. [Cisgender](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisgender). Thus it is not logically a gender identity itself. I take the question to refer to these terms that relate to the cis/trans nature of the relationship between gender identity and sex. Having said that I am aware that some people are now self-identifying as cis or trans so it has now become a gender identity.

Comment: David Robinson - "I am aware that some people are now self-identifying as cis or trans so it has now become a gender identity." - that is my point.

Comment: Yes, one can say that *cis-* and *trans-* are, in a way, gender identities, but it seems that what the OP is seeking is something narrower: a hypernym for *cis-* and *trans-* that is **not**, at the same time, a hypernym for *male*, *female*, etc.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_identity) says "Gender identity is the personal sense of one's own gender. Gender identity can correlate with a person's assigned sex at birth or can differ from it." Whether you are cis or trans means whether they are or are not so correlated, respectively.

"**Trans status**" is used for the concept the OP seeks a name for. Unfortunately, "X's trans status" could be misunderstood as "the fact that X is trans" rather than "whether X is trans or not". (Much as "the film's length" could be taken as either "how much time the film lasts" or "the fact that the film lasts a long time".)

["Sexual Orientation, Gender and Trans Status Monitoring"](https://www.switchboard.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/LGBT-HIP-Monitoring-Report-April-2018.pdf) -- Brighton & Hove LGBT Switchboard (Note Gender and Trans Status being listed as two different concepts.)

["Getting Equalities Monitoring Right"](https://www.scottishtrans.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/getting_equalities_monitoring_right.pdf) -- Scottish Trans and Stonewall Scotland. p.7 "If they dont' want to share their sexual orientation, gender identity or trans status with their employer, they don't have to."

Comment: This term, imperfect as it is, may be the closest that one can get to what the OP is seeking. If one needs to use the concept only once in a given text, it is probably better to just say 'whether one is cis or trans', but *trans status* may be useful in a text in which it will be used a number of times.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for **[gender identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_identity)**

"My gender identity is cis." Or more commonly "I identify as cis."

Cis and trans being two, of many, ways that people identify their gender.

[Transgender](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/transgender) offering:

- noting or relating to a person whose **gender identity** does not correspond to that person’s biological sex assigned at birth

[Cisgender](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/cisgender) offering:

- Also cis·gen·dered. noting or relating to a person whose **gender identity** corresponds with that person’s biological sex assigned at birth.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_identity} says "Gender identity is the personal sense of one's own gender.[1] Gender identity can correlate with a person's assigned sex at birth or can differ from it." Whether you are cis or trans means whether they are or are not so correlated, respectively. "Trans status" is used for the concept the OP seeks a name for. Unfortunately, "X's trans status" could be misunderstood as "the fact that X is trans" rather than "whether X is trans or not".

Comment: How exactly is this answer supposed to differ from the answer that was posted, several months earlier, by Mr. Harvey?